# Excel data through SQL Query needs variable

Tags: sql, excel, variables

I have a SQL Query pulled into Excel but my query needs a variable defined.

I have seen similar suggestions to edit the query within Excel to allow for the input of the variable when refreshing. I've tried inserting:

```
   DECLARE @POSTDATE                 datetime = "?"
```

and
       DECLARE @POSTDATE                 datetime = [Sheet2!A1]

but everything gives me an error message: Invalid column name 'Sheet2!A1' or Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

If I hardcode '12/11/2014' in for the variable everything work fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your full query including quotes?  You need to make sure that you have the "variable" in the proper quotes such as `"DECLARE @POSTDATE datetime = " & Range("Sheet2!A1")` OR `"DECALRE @POSTDATE = """ & Range("Sheet1!A1") & """` if you need the date to be inside quotes

Comment: I don't follow. There aren't any quotes normally. My code usually looks like this:                                                              DECLARE @POSTDATE                 datetime = '12/11/2014'            single quotes

Comment: Are you using VBA or are you doing this through a normal Excel sheet?

Comment: a normal excel sheet - no vba